# passing huge string in intent.putExtra() shows memory error

Tags: android, android-intent, out-of-memory

passing huge string in intent.putExtra() shows memory issue and results in crashing of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You cannot put large objects in an `Intent` like that. If you need to pass large objects you will need to use another method:

- Store the object in a `static` variable that can be directly accessed by the sending and receiving `Activity`
- Store the object in a database
- Store the object in a file